# Asynchronous Function how to?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm discovering Express and Asynchronous / Functionnal

```
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  let User = require('../models/user')
  User.is_complete(id, (validate) => {
    console.log(validate)
  })
  User.find(id, (user) => {
    console.log(user)
    res.render('users/index', {user: user, validate: validate})
  })
})
```

I would like to render the view with 2 variables:
validate of User.is_complete and user of User.find

How could I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to nest the functions.  So when User.is_complete is finished, it will call the User.find in the callback function.

```
User.is_complete(id, (validate) => {
  User.find(id, (user) => {
    console.log(user)
    res.render('users/index', {user: user, validate: validate})
 });
});
```

You should also look up emitting events.  This is another way to handle async code.